# html title(tooltip) is not working in opera and IE-6

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, struts

Hi i am using html 'title' attribute to providing tooltip for select options in html. it working fine Mozilla, chrome, safari,IE(except v.6) but not in opera. is there any way to show dynamic tool tip in opera or browser independent?

Comment: Have you tried the `alt` attribute?

Comment: There are endless jQuery tooltip plugins; there are 30 options listed just within this single article: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

HTML:

```
 <img src=".." />

<span class="tooltip">Tooltip</span>
```

CSS:

```
   .tooltip {
     display: none;
  }


   img:hover + .tooltip {
      display: block;
   }
```

JSBin - http://jsbin.com/ejakeb/7/edit